# Why is jasmine-expect not validating that an error was thrown?

Tags: javascript, jasmine-node

I have a function that throws an error that I am testing.  Here is the function:

```
parse: function(input) {
        var results = {};       
        var that = this;
        input.forEach(function(dependency) {
            var split = dependency.split(": ");
            var lib = split[0];
            var depen = split[1];       
            if(depen === undefined) {
                throw new Error('Invalid input. Requires a space after each colon.')
            }
            results[lib] = depen;
        });
        return results;
    }
```

When I test this function, I hit the error code and want to validate that an error is being thrown.  Here is my test code:

```
var invalidInput = ['Service1: ', 'Service2:stuff'] 
expect(manager.parse(invalidInput)).toThrowError();
```

But my test fails.  Here is my stack trace:

```
Failures:

  1) dependency.js input should require a space after each colon as specified by requirements
   Message:
     Error: Invalid input. Requires a space after each colon.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Invalid input. Requires a space after each colon.
    at /Users/name/Development/sight/dependency.js:49:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.module.exports.parse (/Users/name/Development/sight/dependency.js:44:9)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/name/Development/sight/spec/dependency.spec.js:34:12)
```

I am using `jasmine-expect` to test for the error being thrown.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass a function as parameter to `expect` in conjunction with `toThrow` or `toThrowError`.

```
var invalidInput = ['Service1: ', 'Service2:stuff'] 
expect(function () { manager.parse(invalidInput); }).toThrow();
```

or

```
var invalidInput = ['Service1: ', 'Service2:stuff'] 
expect(function () { manager.parse(invalidInput); }).toThrowError(Error);
```

Comment: That didn't work.  I got this error. `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toThrowError'`

Comment: When I used `toThrow('Invalid input. Requires a space after each colon.')` that did work.

Comment: @jhamm My bad... the matcher without arguments is called just `toThrow` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Seens `toThrowError` to require arguments. Try to set arguments: it can be an expected error message or type, or both.

```
expect(manager.parse(invalidInput)).toThrowError('Invalid input. Requires a space after each colon.');
```

For ignoring error message you may use `toThrow`. From [documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html):

```
it("The 'toThrow' matcher is for testing if a function throws an exception", function() {
    var foo = function() {
      return 1 + 2;
    };
    var bar = function() {
      return a + 1;
    };

    expect(foo).not.toThrow();
    expect(bar).toThrow();
  });

  it("The 'toThrowError' matcher is for testing a specific thrown exception", function() {
    var foo = function() {
      throw new TypeError("foo bar baz");
    };

    expect(foo).toThrowError("foo bar baz");
    expect(foo).toThrowError(/bar/);
    expect(foo).toThrowError(TypeError);
    expect(foo).toThrowError(TypeError, "foo bar baz");
  });
});
```

Comment: I used your `expect` statement and got the same error.

Comment: `toThrow` works for me but when I am using `toThrowError` then I am always getting: "toThrowError is not a function". Any idea where this comes from?